# How to get a shell scripted change to be recognised by an open application

Tags: excel, vba, macos, shell, applescript

I have a particular problem because of a bug affecting date formatting in `VBA/Excel 2011` for `Mac OSX 10.10`.

I have found that I can work around the bug by changing the Region setting - in `SystemPreferences / Language & Region` - to a non-GMT locale. For instance, if I change Region from `United Kingdom` to `Italy`, the bug **doesn't** occur.

I've been developing a macro that runs an `AppleScript`, that in turn runs a shell script, to change the setting using the defaults utility. The shell script I'm using is this:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleLocale en_GB
```

The intention being that on opening Excel, the the value of `AppleLocale` is changed, the bug is gone and then, on closing, the value of `AppleLocale` is reverted to what it was previously.

Changing the setting of `AppleLocale` programmatically on opening Excel works fine. But Excel only picks up this change if I then restart the application. However, if I make the change to the Region setting using the System Preferences GUI, then I don't need to restart Excel for it to recognise the change.

I really want to avoid GUI Scripting, so I'm wondering if some clever bod out there might know why this scripted change isn't recognised. Can I do something else to force Excel to recognise the system change?